# Segmentation fault when using Java API of rhapsody

Tags: java, rhapsody

I am trying to use Java API Call specifically -> RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication() and once the program exits, there is a segmentation fault. I can't find the location of the core dump, so asking if anyone has seen this issue. The model is open in the background and the call returns an object to that. (It is not null). The Rhapsody version is 8.3.1 and am on Linux.

./runSampleClass Segmentation fault (core dumped) $RHAPSODY_PATH/jdk/jre/bin/java -Djava.library.path=$RHAPSODY_PATH/Share/JavaApi -classpath .:$RHAPSODY_PATH/Share/JavaApi/rhapsody.jar SampleClass $1 $2

Thanks

Code -

```
         public class SampleClass {
             public static void main (String [ ] args) {
                String modelName = args[0];
                String root = args[1];

                IRPApplication app = 
                    RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication();
                if (app == null){
                    System.out.println(" failure ");
                }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Java doesn't "segfault".  What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: Okay, so now what's `runSampleClass` got in it?

Comment: runSampleClass is a bash script which sets paths and calls the above java program, that's about it